# Using ArcReader for printing to PDF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, pdf, basemap, arcreader, arcgis-publisher

At my job, most people have ArcReader and the 2 GIS staff will create PMF for people so they can use them for projects and reporting. Lately we've been having an issue where the ESRI basemaps will have chunks missing and a JPG logo (bottom middle) wont show up. These all happen when our colleagues are trying to print to PDF from ArcReader.

Does not happen in ArcMap, just Reader.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

This is an 11x17 map layout...logo issue doesn't happen in 8.5x10 layout. 
[image: Basemap]

Comment: Have you tried exporting to a different format and then converting to PDF?

Comment: Does ArcReader have export options like Compress Vector Graphics and Embed All Document Fonts?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience... It's a memory issue (or lack thereof) on the user's computer. Unless you're saying the same person with ArcMAP is having the issue when printing from ArcReader?
We've had this happen in programs outside of ArcGIS.
Memory memory memory